# Orchard Emailing Errors

Tags: error-handling, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

I am using Orchard to power a new site and when I try to enable my new theme (even in preview mode) I get "The page cannot be displayed because of an internal server error." I've tried changing customErrors in the web.config to be Off and that didn't change anything so I started playing with log4net's configuration. The config I have is below:

```
<appender name="error-file" type="Orchard.Logging.OrchardFileAppender">
<!-- error log: only ERROR and FATAL subset of debug log -->
<file value="App_Data/Logs/orchard-error" />
<appendToFile value="true" />
<!-- immediate flush on error log, to avoid data loss with sudden termination -->
<immediateFlush value="false" />
<staticLogFileName value="false" />
<rollingStyle value="Date" />
<datepattern value="-yyyy.MM.dd'.log'" />
<!-- prevent orchard.exe from displaying locking error messages -->
<lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
<layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
  <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %logger - %message%newline" />
</layout>
</appender>

<appender name="SmtpAppender" type="log4net.Appender.SmtpAppender">
<threshold value="WARN"/>
<to value="to@email.com" />
<from value="from@email.com" />
<subject value="Site Error" />
<smtpHost value="mailserver.com" />
<bufferSize value="2147483647" />
<lossy value="false" />
<layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
  <conversionPattern value="%newline%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline%newline%newline" />
</layout>
```

In the first part of the config, it is incredibly touchy. If I change appendToFile to false (implying create a new file for every error), nothing gets logged and no file is created. When it's false an error log gets created but nothing is written to it (implying it's buffered). Also, when I change "immediateFlush" to true, no error log is written/created. I tried adding the email configuration information based on searching Bing/Google, but it does nothing (tried buffer sizes of 1 and int.MaxValue). No error is logged for that and no email is sent.

All I need to do is figure out what the error is, but I'm blocked at every turn and don't have access to the web server itself to view the Event Log. Any suggestions here? One other thing is I've restarted the app pool a few times hoping that would cause pending errors to log, but no luck there either - the file size stays at 0.

Comment: Why do you need to change anything? Can't you just look in app_data\logs?

Comment: The log file's size was always 0, even after restarting the app. I would get that "internal server error" message, but whenever I tried to look at the log it was always empty. I ended up figuring it out by putting the site on a dedicated server I had access to until I could figure out the error, but getting emailed whenever something occurs would be preferred. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: You might want to ask that using the log4net tag, instead of Orchard.

Answer (score 0):

In your example the `<appender name="SmtpAppender" type="log4net.Appender.SmtpAppender">` is not closed with `</appender>`

Is it well closed on your server?

Comment: Yep, it is closed there. I'm just not good at copy/paste apparently :-) Any other thoughts?